# Use VBA to paste values from one table to another

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I have the following VBA code that takes a single row from Sheet "Tabled data", copies the data, then pastes the data into the next available row in Sheet "Running list". However the original row has formulas and I need the values to paste, not the formulas. I've seen numerous ways to do it with `Range.PasteSpecial` but this code didn't use `Range` and I'm not sure how to incorporate it.

Note: I modified this code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx. It originally had an `IF` statement to match content in a cell then paste it in a certain sheet according to the content in the cell. I only had one sheet to copy to and didn't need the `IF`. I don't really need to find the last row of data to copy either as it will only ever be one row with range of `A2:N2`. But if I take out the `FinalRow` section and the `For` and replace with `Range("A2:N2")` it doesn't work so I left those in.

Any guidance on how to add in the `PasteValues` property without making this more complicated? I'm also open to simplification of the `For` or `FinalRow` variable such as using `Range`. I'm only sort of familiar with VBA, having done a few things with it, but usually after much searching and modifying code.

```
Public Sub CopyData()
Sheets("Tabled data").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 ' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
    Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 14).Copy
    Sheets("Running list").Select
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Tabled data").Select
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution. I recorded a macro to get the paste special in there and added the extra code to find the next empty row:

```
Sub Save_Results()
' Save_Results Macro
  Sheets("Summary").Select 'renamed sheets for clarification, this was 'Tabled data'
'copy the row  
  Range("Table1[Dataset Name]").Select
  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
  Selection.Copy
' paste values into the next empty row
  Sheets("Assessment Results").Select
  Range("A2").Select
  NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
' Return to main sheet      
Sheets("Data Assessment Tool").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully we can actually make this more simple.

```
Public Sub CopyRows()
    Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'check if the last cell found is empty
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1)) = True Then
        'if it is empty, then we should fill it
        nextrow = lastrow
    Else
        'if it is not empty, then we should not overwrite it
        nextrow = lastrow + 1
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Cells(nextrow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

**edit**: I expanded it a little so that there won't be a blank line at the top

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the data all at once, no need to do it a row at a time.

```
Sub CopyData()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabled data")
        Dim sourceRange As Range
        Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(getLastRow(.Range("A1").Parent), 14))
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Running list")
        Dim pasteRow As Long
        Dim pasteRange As Range
        pasteRow = getLastRow(.Range("A1").Parent) + 1
        Set pasteRange = .Range(.Cells(pasteRow, 1), .Cells(pasteRow + sourceRange.Rows.Count, 14))
    End With

    pasteRange.Value = sourceRange.Value

End Sub
Function getLastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional colNum As Long = 1) As Long

    getLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Load_Click()

    Call ImportInfo

End Sub

Sub ImportInfo()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim ActiveListWB As Workbook
    Dim check As Integer

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set WS2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("KE_RAW")
        confirm = MsgBox("Select (.xlsx) Excel file for Data transfer." & vbNewLine & "Please ensure the sheets are named Sort List, Second and Third.", vbOKCancel)

    If confirm = 1 Then
        FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
                Title:="Select Active List to Import", MultiSelect:=False)

        If FileName = "False" Then
                MsgBox "Import procedure was canceled"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Call CleanRaw
                Set ActiveListWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        End If

        Set WS1 = ActiveListWB.Sheets("Sort List")
        WS1.UsedRange.Copy 'WS2.Range("A1")
       ' WS2.Range("A1").Select
        WS2.UsedRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        'WS2.Range ("A1")
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False

     'Call ClearFormulas

       ' Call RefreshAllPivotTables

        Sheets("Key Entry Data").Select
        'Sheets("Raw").Visible = False
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Data has been imported to workbook"

    Else
        MsgBox "Import procedure was canceled"
    End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub CleanRaw()

    Sheets("KE_RAW").Visible = True
    Sheets("KE_RAW").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```